# SystemSettings Class caching within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, settings

We're trying to implement an efficient SystemSettings module for our Rails app, which will be based on Redis.

This should be as fast as possible since we're using the SystemSettings module in almost every request. Therefore, we're trying to decrease the overhead which will be created from calling this module down to a minimum.

The module will also contain a matching web UI for adding/removing/updating values.

The simplest implementation would obviously be to call the Redis server on each operation, but since our Redis service is located in a separated server than our web servers, this will obviously create a network overhead for every operation, Something which we're trying to avoid.

We're looking for a way to cache the values for a period of time, and during this time, just return the cached results instead of calling our Redis service.

The only good solution we came up with was to use `ActionDispatch::Callbacks` in order to determine if the time has arrived for updating the settings cache. The thing is that for me it seems wrong to base the refreshment of the cache based on some random user request.

We were also thinking about creating a small script which will run every 5 minutes or so, that will call a specific URL which will 'trigger' an action that will initiate the cache refresh. The problem with this solution is that this will only result a cache refresh of one of our Passenger processes (the one which handled the request), and not all of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that for me it seems wrong to base the refreshment of the cache based on some random user request.

Not at all. You don't need to clear the cache unless you serve requests, so a random request is as good place as any. Notice that with any cache setting you trade performance due to localized data for potential problems with consistency. Cache invalidation is such a problem.

First thing I'd do in your case is to really actually **measure** if you need to have a localized in-process cache. Redis is extremely quick and sending it multiple small requests is actually a good usage pattern for this server. You may find that network overhead is not really a problem. It may well turn out that this overhead is only a fraction of your whole response time (not to mention rendering and assets time in a browser which greatly affect user experience).

Moreover, if you don't really measure, how would you know that you improved the situation and by how much? Maybe 50 lines of extra code and added complexity is not worth 20ms of speedup per request? Without hard data you can't really make an informed decision here.

Having said that, and assuming you really need it, I would implement cache invalidation along with the cache reading code. Store an expiration time for each entry upon writing and when reading check if the time is in the past. If it is, it's time to update the cache.

In Rails you can use `MemoryStore` with `expires_in` option, e.g.:

```
cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: 5.minutes)
cache.fetch('configuration_key') do
  # your redis contacting code
end
```